# JEST TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm desperate for help here.  I'm trying to test a function with Jest but I'm stuck on one thing.  When I try to mock the fetch request I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

The function I'm trying to test is this:

```js
export const updateUI = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('/sentiment');
  console.log(res);
  
  try {
    console.log(res.data);
    const allData = await res.json();
    console.log(allData);
    document.getElementById("polarity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
    document.getElementById("polarityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
    document.getElementById("subjectivity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
    document.getElementById("subjectivityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        
    return allData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error');
    }
};
```

The test I'm trying to run is this:

```js
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import "core-js/stable";
import "fetch-mock";

const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');
fetchMock.config.sendAsJson = true;  //I've tried with and without this part and I get the same error

import updateUI from './updateUI';
import { isIterable } from "core-js";

describe('updateUI', () => {
  it('can fetch', async () => {
    fetchMock.get('/sentiment', {polarity: 'polarity', polarity_confidence: 'polarity confidence', subjectivity: 'subjectivity', subjectivity_confidence: 'subjectivity confidence'});
    const res = await updateUI('/sentiment');
    const allData = await res.json();

    expect(allData.polarity).toEqual('polarity');
    expect(allData.polarity_confidence).toEqual('polarity confidence');
    expect(allData.subjectivity).toEqual('subjectivity');
    expect(allData.subjectivity_confidence).toEqual('subjectivity confidence');
    });
});
```

I really have no idea where to go from here.  Why won't it get the json object? Is it because my updateUI function calls the json object in the try{} part of the function? If that is the case how do I test it?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here

- In your test you are passing string like this `const res = await updateUI('/sentiment');`  which wouldn't matter as updateUI doesn't take any parameter.
- In the next line you are doing `res.json()` which wouldn't work as from your actual method you are only returning response. You in your test you don't need to do `.json()`. This is the reason you are getting undefined as there is no json function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. More info can be found on [codegrepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/jest+mockimplementation+response+json)

> Make sure the `Promise.resolve` is used well and the mocked and api data both has the same format.

```js
const mockFetchUserData = (data) => {
  return global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 
    Promise.resolve({
      json: () => data
    })
  )
}

it('Display empty list of users', async () => {
// Data can be empty array or array of data  
await mockFetchUserData([])

  await act(async () =>
    render(
      <Router>
        <User />
      </Router>
    )
  })
  const findSearchButtonText = screen.getByText('Search') // is search button rendered
  expect(findSearchButtonText.type).toBe('submit') // is type submit
}
```